# Spark Error message: Please consider a new data model based on the query pattern instead of using ALLOW FILTERING

Tags: apache-spark, datastax, datastax-enterprise, datastax-startup

My DSE Opscenter sends me this message:

Please consider a new data model based on the query pattern instead of using ALLOW FILTERING.

And after changing my spark code I already removed the below column value from my query. But the below error message still keeps popping up. I don't know why? Also the error message only occurs in my OPScenter on in the actual table. Thanks for your help.

Query:

```
select * from dse_perf.node_slow_log
```

Column value/ error mesage

```
SELECT "XXX", "XXX", "XXX", "likes", "XXX" FROM "XXX"."axes" WHERE token("article") > ? AND token("article") <= ?   ALLOW FILTERING
```

Please consider a new data model based on the query pattern instead of using ALLOW FILTERING.

Comment: So to clarify the `node_slow_log` table is still showing the old query?

Comment: Yes it is. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Opscenter is warning you that your request can be pretty expensive and suggesting your review the use case.

"Allow Filtering" can be pretty expensive as described here:

http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/allow-filtering-explained-2

It maybe your use falls into the OK category - in which case you can ignore the warning.  If not - it may be worth looking at other ways of modelling your data that allow you to sort it in a more efficient manner.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But what I was saying in my question is that i already changed this according to your best practices and the error message still shows up. Could read my post again and let me know your feedback? thanks

Comment: Odd - what's the date on the queries in the slow logs?  They should expire via ttl eventually.